# stacking relationships to get count() laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have 4 tables: schools, courses, rosters, students. The "schools" hasMany courses and hasMany "students". The rosters hasMany "students". The courses hasOne "rosters". Right? I'm confused too. So in my controller, I queried the schools table, and it gives me access to "one level" of relationships. Meaning I can do $schools->courses->date or $schools->students->first_name etc... in my @foreach loops. Here's where i'm getting lost. The rosters table is basically an entire table of foreign key relations. It has no unique data on its own other than the timestamps and primary ID. I have a table where i'm trying to display the all the courses for a school, along with the total value of students enrolled in that particular course. So i'm foreach-ing every course for the school, easy enough. But then i'm trying to pull the count() from the rosters table for every student in that course and reflect it on that table row.

So to recap, one table row per course. Trying to get the students enrolled in each respective course. My controller query is basically just

```
$schools::School::findOrFail($id);
```

From that, i can get all the course and student info, but i can't figure out how to basically stack the relationship to equal something like this:

school->course->roster->total number of students.

I'm not even trying to keep this all in the same query. I can't even figure out how to do a query in the controller and just pass a final value in a variable along to the view. I'd be totally ok with doing a second query in the controller to get the value of the rosters but i can't wrap my head around multiple courses per school in one query with one roster per course. I'm confusing myself typing this question lol. Can anyone offer advice?

[image]

```
class Roster extends Model
{
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
    }

    public function students(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Student', 'student_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Course extends Model
{
    public function schools()
    {
        return $this-> belongsTo('App\School');
    }

    public function roster()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Roster', 'class_id', 'id');
    }


}

class Student extends Model
{

    public function grade(){

      return $this->hasOne('App\Grade');
    }

    public function school()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\School');
    }

    public function drive()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Drive');
    }

    public function roster()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Roster');
    }

}

class School extends Model
{
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Course');
    }

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
    }

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee','school_id', 'id');
    }

    public function drive()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Drive');
    }
    public function car(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Car', 'schools_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean roster is the immediate/pivot table between students and course?

Comment: please refer to the screen shot i just posted of my database focused on the rosters table. what i just tried to do in my view using blade was @php ($number = count($class->roster)). but this only prints the number 1 because there's only one roster per class

Comment: sorry the image is blocked by my proxy, (i cant control it)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kgaF1XKnez7-Kxbxzr9rnEcFUK5J9wmN/view?usp=sharing      try this link to a google drive

Comment: can't you just do `$school->course->roster->students->count();`?

Comment: let me try plugging that in

Comment: foreach($school->courses as $class)
      
      php ($number = $class->roster->students->count())
       <tr>
           <td>{{$class->class_code}}</td>
           <td>{{$class->day_1}}</td>
            <td>{{$class->day_2}}</td>
            <td>{{$class->day_3}}</td>
            <td>{{$class->day_4}}</td>
           <td>{{$number}}</td>
           <td></td>
         
         </tr>
        endforeach

this is what i just did. it prints "0" in the <td> even though there should be 4 students found (please don't comment on the absence of the "@", the comments here won't allow

Comment: wow, that looks like trash. how do i post code in a comment?

Comment: surround it with `

Comment: `@foreach($school->courses as $class)
      
      @php ($number = $class->roster->students->count())
       <tr>
           <td>{{$class->class_code}}</td>
           <td>{{$class->day_1}}</td>
            <td>{{$class->day_2}}</td>
            <td>{{$class->day_3}}</td>
            <td>{{$class->day_4}}</td>
           <td>{{$number}}</td>
           <td></td>
         
         </tr>
        @endforeach`

Comment: i don't think that worked XD

Comment: without space after the `. just edit your previous comment.

Comment: did you setup relationships? if so, please include it in your question.

Comment: ok, you can check the question. i edited at the bottom of the file with the relationships for all four models

Comment: if you `dd($class->roster->students)` is it an empty collection?

Comment: it says "property 'roster' does not exist on this collection"

Comment: how does this `$class->roster->students->count()` result to `0` if `$class->roster->students` throws an error?

Comment: where did you want me to die dump at? i put it in the controller. should i try it in the view?

Comment: yes. in the view, from where it is declared.

Comment: ok, yes, it is an empty collection.

Comment: then that's the answer why it is 0. it's either you're querying the wrong queries, or there are no data in the database which correspond to your query.

Comment: i know :( i feel like this may be an impossible question for someone to answer without looking at the code for the whole project. thanks for your time mate, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Another thing: If the school `->hasMany()` students, a student cannot `->hasOne()` school. It has to have a `->belongsTo` relationship. `->hasOne()` means that the school should have a `user_id`.

Comment: @RobanReuvers, thanks for catching that. i just got to work so won't be able to test it until I get home but i don't think i would have ever seen that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get **school** from its ID.

```
$school = School::findOrFail($id);
```

Then, You have **hasMany** relation with courses, so you will get results of school courses by this

```
$courses = $school->courses;
```

Now you have array result in courses so you can use **foreach** loop on it

```
$rosters = [];
foreach($courses as $course)
{
   $rosters[] = $cource->roster;
}
```

After this,
 Roster have **hasMany** relation with students, so you can do for each rosters

```
$students = [];
foreach($rosters as $roster){
   $students[$roster->id] = $roster->students->count();
}
```

Here, in **$students** you will get students count for the different roster.

Comment: yes. that is fine. i'm trying to figure out how to stack multiple relationships. i can't get the count of students from the roster of each course in the table. So right now, my table renders one course per row. At the end of the row, I'm trying to display total number of students in that particular course. The database has a course_id in the rosters table but i can't figure out how to access it either in eloquent or blade

Comment: right now, in my database for school 1, i have 4 students enrolled in 2 different classes. This information is held in the rosters table. i'm trying to get the total number of students per class. So in the rosters table, i have a school_id, a course_id, and a student_id. I have already filtered down to school and course. I can run a foreach and get those values. but i can't get the count of students in each roster.

Comment: I have updated my answer. figure it out and tell me if you have any query.

Comment: what variable to i output between the double braces?

Comment: sorry didn't get you?

Comment: so i pasted your code into my view. but i need to print the number of students in each roster. how do i type {{$value}} with your code? what variable name goes between the curly braces?

Comment: you will get the result in **$students** for each roster. And in **$students** array you have  **$roster->id** as **key** and **count** value of students in **value**. Now you can pass whatever you need to show in your view with your controller.

Comment: yeah welcome. If still, you have any query about it you can ask me.